# Image size issue in Owl Carousel

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a WordPress theme. Initially its bootstrap template has been created. Currently I have an issue in its slider for the testimonials section.

I am using Owl Carousel to create the slider. I have included the following shortcode inside the `div` in my `index.php` file:

```
<?php
    echo do_shortcode('[owl-carousel category="testimonial" singleItem="true" autoPlay="true"]');
?>
```

The slider includes a statement given by the client with the client's image at the bottom in a circle. For the image, I have its CSS looking like:

```
.img-circle {
  margin-top: 20px;
  height: auto;
  width: 100px;
 }
```

Though the width of the image has been specified but the image picks up the entire width of the `div` of which it is a part. I want to display only one client in one slide, so I have used `singleItem="true"` in the short-code. Have been unable to get the required image dimensions. How to contain the image to the required dimensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give the width and height attributes to the img markup. Also, it **will need to be** `display: block` in order to ignores owl-carousel's 100% width.

You could also include a wrapper around it, will work better.

CSS

```
.wrapper-circle {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper-circle">
    <img src="" alt="">
</div>
```

If you can`t edit HTML, try applying CSS to your img tag instead:

```
display: block;
width: 50px;
height: auto;
```

Check this for more details: http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/one.html

Comment: I fixed it using `max-width` attribute and then setting the height to `auto`. Thanks for your reply.